# How to control test case run through an excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, selenium, frameworks, webdriver

**My question is actually a design problem.** I am using python + selenium for automation. PyUnit is the unit framework used. I have a sheet in an excel where I have 2 columns- TestCaseID and Run. TestCaseID will have the testcase id in it and Run will have either Y or N signifying whether that test case should be runnable or not. What I am trying to do is read a particular test case Id from this sheet and see what does it have as it's run value, Y or N. If it is Y, then this test case will be executed by the unit framework else it will not be run.

Here is an excerpt of a test case that I have written:

`class Test_ID_94017(unittest.TestCase):

```
ex = Excel()
def setUp(self):
    self.ex.setUpASheetInExcel('Select_Test_Cases_To_Run')
    if self.ex.getTestCaseRunStatusFromExcel("94017") == "Y":
        self.driver = Browser().createBrowserDriver()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.ex.setUpASheetInExcel('Login')
    else:
        return

def test_CCPD_Regression001_PER_Custom_Check(self):
    //do something
```

The definition for getTestCaseRunStatusFromExcel(testCaseId) method is:

`def getTestCaseRunStatusFromExcel(self, testCaseId):

```
    i=1
    while self.workSheet.cell_value(i,0).value != testCaseId:
        i+=1
    return self.workSheet.cell_value(i,1).value
```

Here are the problems I am facing:

1. How should I give a condition in my existing code so that only for Y, my test case executes? Should I give an if condition in setUp method for that test case class as I have mentioned in my code above?
2. Is the way in which I am trying to iterate over the rows in a column (of the excel sheet) correct until I find my testcase ID and get its corresponding Run value (Y or N)?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I implemented similar design for selenium+testng suite. After reading the execution flags from excel, i create the testng.xml dynamically and run the same xml. TestNG provides features for xml to be created and executed dynamically. Not sure if you have anything similar in PyUnit. I hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand your solution. How is the dynamically generated xml helping you to control your test case execution flow?

Comment: Only the scripts marked for execution in excel are added to the dynamically generated xml.